# How to put a fragment list inside of activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know how to replace a whole activity layout with a fragments list, but how do I nest a fragments list inside of a part of an activity layout?

**EDIT**: I have attached a picture of what Im trying to achieve at the bottom

***This is what I know how to do:***

I have an actionbar with 3 tabs below it.
When a tab has been clicked a feed of fragments comes on screen (like the feed of the FB app)

***This is what I dont know how to do:***
I have an actionbar
Below it I have some content that I want to remain static
Below the static content I want to nest a feed like the one described above.

***Here is what I've tried:***

```
public class MyProfileActivity extends SherlockListFragment {

      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Samsung Galaxy S3", "Samsung Galaxy S3", "Samsung Galaxy S3",
            "Samsung Galaxy S3", "Samsung Galaxy S3", "Samsung Galaxy S3", "Samsung Galaxy S3", "Samsung Galaxy S3",
            "Samsung Galaxy S3", "Samsung Galaxy S3" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.my_profile_feed_custom, R.id.tvProfileFeedItemName, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
```

And I want to place this inside of here:

```
    public class MyProfile extends ActionBarAndSlidingMenu implements OnClickListener{
        private TableRow myProfileActionButtonsHolder;
        private TableRow myProfileStatsHolder;
        private TableRow myProfileActivityHolder;


        public MyProfile() {
            super(R.string.app_name);
        }



        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            setContentView(R.layout.user_profile);


            myProfileActionButtonsHolder = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.userProfileActionButtonsHolder); 

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.userProfileActionButtonsHolder,
 new MyProfileActionButtonsFragment()).commit();
 //this one works - it places 
//two buttons below the user info (it is a single fragment)

            myProfileStatsHolder = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.myProfileStatsHolder);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myProfileStatsHolder, 
new MyProfileUserStatsFragment()).commit(); 
//this one  also works - it places user 
//activity stats pane below the user info (it is a single fragment)


            myProfileActivityHolder = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.myProfileActivityHolder);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myProfileActivityHolder,
 new MyProfileActivity()).commit();
 //this one doesnt work. It doesnt place the 
//list of fragments below the stats pane. (it is a fragment list)
    }
```

This is where placing the fragment list works:

public class Home extends ActionBarAndSlidingMenu {

```
public Home() {
    super(R.string.app_name);
}

//String userEmail; 
//String reqFrom = "";
CharSequence[] tabsText = {"Items", "People", "Places", };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab itemsFeedTab = actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab peopleFeedTab = actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab placesFeedTab = actionBar.newTab();

    Fragment itemsFeedFragment = new FeedItems();
    Fragment peopleFeedFragment = new FeedPeople();
    Fragment placesFeedFragment = new FeedPlaces();

    itemsFeedTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(itemsFeedFragment));
    peopleFeedTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(peopleFeedFragment));
    placesFeedTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(placesFeedFragment));

    actionBar.addTab(itemsFeedTab, 0, true);
    actionBar.addTab(peopleFeedTab, 1, false);
    actionBar.addTab(placesFeedTab, 2, false);
    configurationz = new Configurationz();
    for(int i = 0; i<actionBar.getTabCount(); i++){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_title, null);
        titleTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.action_custom_title);
        actionBar.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(customView);
}

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.replace(R.id.home, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {  }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {  }
}
```

And the fragment looks the same way as the fragment in the above example.
Here, when I click a tab, it replaces the whole screen contents with a fragment list.

In the above example I only need to replace a part of the screen with a fragment list, but I dont know how.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FrameLayout or ViewFlipper and inside the FrameLayout/ViewFlipper use custom list view to load the data

Comment: which part of my code is invalid? what should I use the FrameLayout for - the parent view or the child view? Should this list view do the job as a custom list view? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: use frame layout as your child view and add custom list view to it.you can get working with frame layout from the link.http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/

Comment: so the fragments part should stay the same, but the layout the fragment uses will be a frame layout framed? I mean this - MyProfileActivity() - will have a layout that is a FrameLayout. Everything in my main class should remain the same? In my main class' layout Im using a table row and Im replacing it with the new fragment. Should I put an empty layout there and replace it with the new one that comes from the fragment?